# How to center a UILabel on UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, uilabel

How can I center the UILabel on the UIView? I am using the following code

```
float width = weatherView.bounds.size.width; 
float height = weatherView.bounds.size.height; 

[self.label setFrame:CGRectMake(width-100,height-100, 100, 100)];
```

Answer (score 104, accepted):

How about:

```
[self.label setCenter:view.center];
```

Comment: that works but if the label is long then it does not center it. It either goes to left or right. I thought the positioned was determined by the center point of the uilabel.

Comment: Well... only if label and view are subviews of the same view. If the label is subview of the view, you must disregard the location and just consider the bounds.

Comment: I added the UILabel using the interface designer (drag and drop). Does that mean it is a subview of the view and I should use bounds.

Comment: self.contentView.center

Comment: This let me to `label.center.y = view.center.y` to only center the y axis. Upvote for that.

Answer (score 39):

If the label is a subview of view:

```
[self.label setCenter:CGPointMake(view.frame.size.width / 2, view.frame.size.height / 2)]
```

Don't use `view.center` unless the label and view have the same superview.

If there is no immediate connection, then you'll have to transform view's center to the coordinate space of label's parent. Then you could use PengOne's answer with the transformed point.

Answer (score 21):

Use NSTextAlignmentCenter if what you have is the label already set and you want to center its content.

```
cell.menuLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

Comment: This is the best answer, having the label frame is centered is not enough for centering the text, very useful if your labels are localized!

Comment: I think it may be the only correct answer to what the OP wants to do. Its what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 16):

A better posible solution is:

**First:** If you are doing this programmatically you'll need to initialize with frame and some customizations:

```
// Simple example
int yPosition = 10;
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, yPosition, self.view.frame.size.width, 0)];
[label setText: @"Testing..."];
[label setBackgroundColor: [UIColor clearColor]];
[label setNumberOfLines: 0];
[label sizeToFit];
```

**Second:** If a label what you are trying to center you can just run this after `setNumberOflines` selector called and `0 value` assigned, your text will have all lines needed, and `sizeToFit` method called to have a good customization, and finally:

```
[self.label setCenter: CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.label.center.y)];
```

This will center `only the X axis`, and the `Y axis` will stay as you desired in the frame initialization.

**PS:** It's also valid if not a `UILabel` but depends on the control you are using will need another simple customization or neither, and if you only want to center programmatically but `interface builder` designed, just need to run the `second code`.

Comment: `self.view.frame.width` should be `self.view.frame.size.width`

Answer (score 3):

PengOne / Alex Lockwood's answer is simple and useful. If you intend to support rotation, add the following to keep it centered:

```
[self.myLabel setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do the trick...
Make sure that your label is set to have centered alignment and is sufficiently big/wide to handle your text string.

```
float viewWidth = weatherView.frame.size.width;
float viewHeight = weatherView.frame.size.height;
float labelWidth = label.frame.size.width;
float labelHeight = label.frame.size.height;

float xpos = (viewWidth/2.0f) - (labelWidth/2.0f);
float ypos = (viewHeight/2.0f) - (labelHeight/2.0f);

[label setFrame:CGRectMake(xpos,ypos,labelWidth,labelHeight)];
```

I think that should do what you are asking for.

Comment: I do not know the size of the label and hence I am using the siteToFit method.

Comment: The code above should still work so long as you call it after whatever initialisation you are doing on the label

Answer (score 2):

There are two possibility if your UILabel is added via .xib or else added programmatically .

If first case i.e added via .xib then you can set the position from xib file size inspector tab with the 'Arrange' property

And if second case persist then you can set as ---  [self.label setCenter:view.center];