# How does one center a UILabel object programmatically in Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

How would I go about centering a UILabel programmatically (my whole app is programmatic eliminating using IB auto layout) in Swift?

I've seen this which seems to answer it for Objective-C:

[How to center a UILabel on UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6753794/how-to-center-a-uilabel-on-uiview)

setCenter doesn't seem to function as such in Swift however.

Comment: Not `setCenter`. `center`. Just set the `center` property. Of course you also need to make the label itself be center-justified. And it needs to be sized to fit its contents. Otherwise it will be centered where you tell it, but the text will not.

Comment: I recommend not to use center. Use NSLayoutConstraint.

Answer (score 4):

Ok apparently it's

```
    UILabel.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, 30, 300, 60)
```

obviously with the first coordinate determining the centering. A similar operation can be performed via CGPoint should you use UILabel.center instead.