# Center Top Label iOS Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

This is my 2nd day in my new job as an iOS Developer. So far I'm really enjoying coding objective-C. How can I make my 1 line label to be center in a parent and at the same time at the top?

What I have done so far:

1. learned how to apply font size and font colors.
2. learned creating ui programmatically.
3. learned adding label to the ui.
4. centering the label, as in in Center of the parent.
5. setting the label numberOfLines to 0.

Here's my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // loading the viewcontroller, load the controllers/objects.

    // set background and title of the view
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:RGB(19,181,234)];
    self.title = @"UI Main";

    // add the label1
    UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 50, 200, 40)];
    [myLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    myLabel.textColor = RGB(255,255,255);
    [myLabel setText:@"Enter Amount"];
    myLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    [myLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"DejaVu Sans" size:10]];
    [myLabel sizeToFit];
    [[self view] addSubview:myLabel];
    // [myLabel release];


}
```

here is my screenshot of my simulator: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AN2JX.png

edit: my question is about getting the size of my parent view so that I can center my controls. But it has been already answered! thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to center a UILabel on UIView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6753794/how-to-center-a-uilabel-on-uiview)

Comment: set **[self.label setCenter:CGPointMake(view.frame.size.width / 2, view.frame.size.height / 2)]**

Comment: Thanks Anbu. You're solution is quite the same with the answer below, but I understand well the answer of Saheb more than yours. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Label has the superview of self.view or you want your label to be at the center of the self.view (UIView), change this

```
int WidthOfLabel = 100;
int someHeight = 50;
UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width/2)-(widthOfLabel/2), 80, widthOfLabel, someHeight)];
myLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

Comment: Hey thank you so much Saheb for giving me idea in centering the X axis of my label! Thanks thanks. I'm learning step by step. And thank you people for not voting down my questions :)

Comment: glad it helped you, best of luck for your job :)