# How do I center a UILabel to a UIView programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uilabel, centering

I have gone through this thread and pretty much tried every suggestion, but still my label refuse to center in the `view`:

[How to center a UILabel on UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6753794/how-to-center-a-uilabel-on-uiview)

This is the closest I get:

[image]

My first thought was that the `view` hides under the `tab bar` but according the the `debug hierarchy` the `view` ends right where the `tab bar` starts.

The code looks like this:

```
    _noExperiences = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    _noExperiences.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.view addSubview:_noExperiences];

    UILabel *nothingToShow = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(_noExperiences.center.x, _noExperiences.center.y, 200, 20)];
    nothingToShow.text = @"HELLO";
    nothingToShow.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    nothingToShow.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [nothingToShow setNumberOfLines: 0];
    [nothingToShow sizeToFit];

    [nothingToShow setCenter: CGPointMake(_noExperiences.center.x, _noExperiences.center.y)];
    [nothingToShow setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"Trebuchet MS" size: 14.0f]];

    [_noExperiences addSubview:nothingToShow];
```

Comment: UILabel *nothingToShow = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(_noExperiences.frame.size.width/2 - 100, _noExperiences.frame.size.height/2 - 10, 200, 20)];

Comment: You can use Autolayout, you can use auto resizing masks,  you can use PinLayout, you can use LayoutKit etc, you can manually layout label in viewWillLayoutSubviews or you can create custom view in root and layout label in layoutSubviews method. There are to many options. Which you prefer more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be ***much*** better off learning / using constraints and auto-layout.

Here is what you are trying to do, but it will ***auto-layout*** correctly for all different devices and rotations:

```
_noExperiences = [UIView new];
_noExperiences.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

UILabel *nothingToShow = [UILabel new];
nothingToShow.text = @"HELLO";
nothingToShow.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
nothingToShow.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[nothingToShow setNumberOfLines: 0];
[nothingToShow setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"Trebuchet MS" size: 14.0f]];

// add _noExperiences to self.view
[self.view addSubview:_noExperiences];

// add nothingToShow to _noExperiences
[_noExperiences addSubview:nothingToShow];

// we'll use auto-layout, so set to NO
_noExperiences.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
nothingToShow.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

// let's respect safe area
UILayoutGuide *g = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide;

[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[

    // constrain _noExperiences view to safe area
    [_noExperiences.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.topAnchor constant:0.0],
    [_noExperiences.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.bottomAnchor constant:0.0],
    [_noExperiences.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.leadingAnchor constant:0.0],
    [_noExperiences.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.trailingAnchor constant:0.0],

    // constrain nothingToShow label centered in _noExperiences view
    [nothingToShow.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:_noExperiences.centerXAnchor],
    [nothingToShow.centerYAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:_noExperiences.centerYAnchor],

]];
```

---

**EDIT**

If you *really* need to support those 7 users who are using an iOS version earlier than 11, you can try this to handle the missing `safeAreaLayoutGuide`:

```
// let's respect safe area for iOS 11+
// or layoutMarginsGuide for earlier
UILayoutGuide *g;
CGFloat standardSpacing = 0.0;

if (@available(iOS 11, *)) {
    // iOS 11 (or newer) ObjC code
    g = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide;
    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
        // constrain _noExperiences view to safe area
        [_noExperiences.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.topAnchor constant:0.0],
        [_noExperiences.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.bottomAnchor constant:0.0],
        [_noExperiences.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.leadingAnchor constant:0.0],
        [_noExperiences.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.trailingAnchor constant:0.0],
    ]];
} else {
    // iOS 10 or older code
    standardSpacing = 8.0;
    g = self.view.layoutMarginsGuide;
    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
        // constrain _noExperiences view to layout margins guide
        [_noExperiences.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.topAnchor constant:standardSpacing],
        [_noExperiences.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.bottomAnchor constant:-standardSpacing],
        [_noExperiences.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.leadingAnchor constant:0.0],
        [_noExperiences.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.trailingAnchor constant:0.0],
    ]];
}

[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[

    // constrain nothingToShow label centered in _noExperiences view
    [nothingToShow.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:_noExperiences.centerXAnchor],
    [nothingToShow.centerYAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:_noExperiences.centerYAnchor],

]];
```

Comment: Sorry for late response, but THANKS! It worked great! Of all the things I've tried, this is the only thing that actually worked. One thing though. `safeAreaLayoutGuide` is only available for iOS 11 and above. Tried skipping it, but it resulted in a mess. How do I get around it for iOS < 11?

Answer (score 3):

please try for swift :

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 21))
        label.center = view.center
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.text = "label"
        self.view.addSubview(label)
```